# VS2010 Adding a breakpoint in RazorGeneratorMvcStart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints, razorgenerator

When I attempt to debug my MVC 3 app a breakpoint is automatically added in the static class `RazorGeneratorMvcStart`

at in the static `Start()` method at the line:

`ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, engine);`

When I delete the breakpoint during the run it still comes back and most pages hit this method several times with each call.

Is there a way I can prevent this breakpoint from being added or what is causing the breakpoint to be added here.  I have checked the files and it does not show the break point there anywhere I can find.  But it gets added to the class every time I hit a view.  When not debugging the file does not show the symbol.  I tried adding and then removing a breakpoint there as well but that has no effect, a breakpoint is added there the next time a view hit.

If I disable the breakpoint and leave the file open in VS it seems to bypass through out that action.  But the next action call the breakpoint returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Debug -> Delete All Breakpoints (Ctrl + Shift + F9).

Comment: This seems to have negated the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the breakpoint when the application is NOT running

Comment: There is not one there to delete.  I have tried adding one then deleting it as well.